# Join 2 Table with same column and display the same column to one single column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables:

1. DATA_IZIN_BODY
2. DATA_IZIN_DETAIL
3. DATA_IZIN_DETAILPC

Here is the sample data :

**DATA_IZIN_BODY**//UPDATE

```
|ID_B|NIK  |PERMIT TYPE|REASON       |NAME  |SUBMISSION DATE  |STATUS  |
|----|-----|-----------|-------------|------|-----------------|--------|
|N1  |1070 |ABSENT     |SICK         |John  |9/5/2019         |PENDING |
|N2  |1088 |LEAVE      |LATE         |Laura |8/6/2019         |APPROVED|
|N3  |1009 |ABSENT     |CANNT ATTND  |Emmet |8/8/2019         |APPROVED|
```

**DATA_IZIN_DETAIL***//UPDATE***

```
|ID  |ID_B |NIK  |DETAIL DATE  |DETAIL HOUR|STATUS  |FLAG|
|----|-----|-----|-------------|-----------|--------|----|
|001 |N1   |1070 |10/5/2019    |08.00      |NULL    |1   |
|002 |N1   |1070 |11/5/2019    |07.00      |NULL    |1   |
|003 |N1   |1070 |12/6/2019    |08.00      |NULL    |1   |
|004 |N3   |1009 |9/8/2019     |09.00      |NULL    |1   |
|005 |N3   |1088 |10/6/2019    |10.00      |NULL    |1   |
|006 |N3   |1009 |11/8/2019    |11.00      |NULL    |1   |
```

**DATA_IZIN_DETAILPC***//UPDATE***

```
|ID  |ID_B|NIK  |DETAIL DATE  |STATUS  |FLAG  |
|----|----|-----|-------------|--------|------|
|001 |N1  |1070 |13/5/2019    |NULL    |2     |
|002 |N1  |1070 |14/6/2019    |NULL    |2     |
|003 |N3  |1009 |12/8/2019    |NULL    |2     |
```

***THE GOAL***

```
|ID  |ID_B|NIK  |NAME  |PERMIT TYPE|REASON     |DETAIL DATE  |STATUS  |FLAG|
|----|----|-----|------|-----------|-----------|-------------|--------|----|
|001 |N1  |1070 |John  |ABSENT     |SICK       |13/5/2019    |NULL    |2   |
|002 |N1  |1070 |John  |ABSENT     |SICK       |14/6/2019    |NULL    |2   |
|003 |N3  |1009 |Emmet |ABSENT     |CANNT ATTND|12/8/2019    |NULL    |2   |
|001 |N1  |1070 |John  |ABSENT     |SICK       |10/5/2019    |NULL    |1   |
|002 |N1  |1070 |John  |ABSENT     |SICK       |11/5/2019    |NULL    |1   |
|003 |N1  |1070 |John  |ABSENT     |SICK       |12/6/2019    |NULL    |1   |
|004 |N3  |1009 |Emmet |ABSENT     |CANNT ATTND|9/8/2019     |NULL    |1   |
|005 |N3  |1088 |Emmet |ABSENT     |CANNT ATTND|10/6/2019    |NULL    |1   |
|006 |N3  |1009 |Emmet |ABSENT     |CANNT ATTND|11/8/2019    |NULL    |1   |
```

And here is my query, tried with case but won't work as expected:

```
select 
    b.izin_id, b.IZIN_NIK
    /*case 
        when pc.Flag = 2 then 'PC'
        when d.Flag = 1 then 'DT'end
        as Flag*/
from DATA_IZIN_BODY b
inner join DATA_IZIN_DETAIL d on d.IZIN_ID = b.IZIN_ID
inner join DATA_IZIN_DETAILPC pc on pc.IZIN_ID = b.IZIN_ID
```

but how do we combine:

- DATA_IZIN_DETAIL.izin_id & DATA_IZIN_DETAILPC.izin_id into 1 column as ID ?
- DATA_IZIN_DETAIL.Flag & DATA_IZIN_DETAILPC.Flag into 1 column as Flag?

***update***

```
ON GOAL : COLUMN ID & FLAG CONTAIN VALUE OF DATA_IZIN_DETAILPC.ID & DATA_IZIN_DETAIL.ID, DATA_IZIN_DETAILPC.FLAG & DATA_IZIN_DETAIL.FLAG
```

***update 2***

```
Data_izin_body 

 1. ID_B : nvarchar 
 2. NIK : nvarchar 
 3. Permit_Type : nvarchar
 4. Reason : nvarchar 
 5. Name : nvarchar 
 6. Submission_Date : smalldatetime
 7. Status : nvarchar

Data_izin_detail

 1. ID : nvarchar
 2. ID_B : nvarchar 
 2. NIK : nvarchar 
 3. Detail_Date : smalldatetime
 4. Detail_Hour : nvarchar
 5. Status : nvarchar
 6. Flag : int

Data_izin_detailpc

 1. ID : nvarchar
 2. ID_B : nvarchar 
 2. NIK : nvarchar 
 3. Detail_Date : smalldatetime
 4. Status : nvarchar
 5. Flag : int
```

Comment: A similar question to this can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854750/join-two-identical-table-structures-with-different-data. Which should give to you the clue on this one.

Comment: You have this fileld name `IZIN_ID` in your sample code but it is not exists in your sample data.. How come?

Comment: this izin_id = id_b sir @VijunavVastivch. sorry for the 
lack of explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the UNION ALL combines the 2 secondary tables. Then the main table joins to that.

```
 SELECT Details.ID,
     b.ID_B,
     b.IZIN_NIK AS NIK,
     b.Name,
     b.[Permit Type],
     b.Reason,
     Details.[Detail Date],
     Details.Status,
     Details.Source,
     Details.Flag
   FROM DATA_IZIN_BODY b
   JOIN 
          (SELECT ID, ID_B, [DETAIL DATE], STATUS, 'DT' AS Source, FLAG
           FROM DATA_IZIN_DETAIL

           UNION ALL

           SELECT ID, ID_B, [DETAIL DATE], STATUS, 'PC' AS Source, FLAG
           FROM DATA_IZIN_DETAILPC) AS Details
   ON b.ID_B = Details.ID_B 
   ORDER BY b.NAME, 
         Details.[DETAIL DATE]
```

Not sure you still need the FLAG column if you have the Source column...

Comment: Ah. Yes. You put the union in a table expression. That's possible too, of course. Since we know little about the context of the data, it's difficult to say which tables are "secondary" tables here... I agree it can be nice to have such a `Source` field in the results, but it's not required based on the info in the question... You might be right about the `Flag` field, but since it's meaning is not known to us, it could represent something else entirely... And I would personally not include an ORDER BY if it is not necessary for getting correct results, like in this case... Good answer though.

Comment: dear @JBrooks, thanks for the help :) finally its met the requirement. really appreciate it! big thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that tables `DATA_IZIN_DETAIL` and `DATA_IZIN_DETAILPC` have the same field structure. If that is intended, you can perform a UNION on two SELECT queries:

```
SELECT [ID], [ID_B], [NIK], [NAME], [DETAIL DATE], [STATUS], [FLAG] FROM [DATA_IZIN_DETAILPC]
UNION ALL
SELECT [ID], [ID_B], [NIK], [NAME], [DETAIL DATE], [STATUS], [FLAG] FROM [DATA_IZIN_DETAIL]
```

**Edit:**

Based on the recent information in your updated question, I would suggest the following query to get your desired results:

```
SELECT
    D.[ID],
    D.[ID_B],
    D.[NIK],
    B.[Name],
    B.[Permit_Type],
    B.[Reason],
    D.[Detail_Date],
    D.[Status],
    D.[Flag]
FROM
    [DATA_IZIN_DETAILPC] AS D
    INNER JOIN [DATA_IZIN_BODY] AS B ON B.[ID_B] = D.[ID_B] --AND B.[NIK] = D.[NIK]
UNION ALL
SELECT
    D.[ID],
    D.[ID_B],
    D.[NIK],
    B.[Name],
    B.[Permit_Type],
    B.[Reason],
    D.[Detail_Date],
    D.[Status],
    D.[Flag]
FROM
    [DATA_IZIN_DETAIL] AS D
    INNER JOIN [DATA_IZIN_BODY] AS B ON B.[ID_B] = D.[ID_B] --AND B.[NIK] = D.[NIK]
```

Comment: well, I do inner join to a 'union' query? I still don't get it. how could i get all the data_izin_body row that related to specific data in 'union' query based on id_b? @Bart Hofland

Comment: and 1 thing, this 2 table doesn't have an identical column. they different on the number of columns @Bart Hofland

Comment: I have seen your query using JOINs. However, looking at the desired result (under "the goal"), I noticed that you simply create a result that contains all the records from tables `DATA_IZIN_DETAILPC` and `DATA_IZIN_DETAIL`. As far as I see, my query does reach your goal. Doesn't it?

Comment: Since I explicitly state all the fields in my SELECT queries, it should not matter if one of the tables contain other fields. It does matter, however, that the seven included fields have the same type in both tables. If that is not the case, my answer will not work for you.

Comment: It is possible to create a query with JOINs, but you have to specify the exact table structure of `DATA_IZIN_DETAIL` and `DATA_IZIN_DETAILPC`. Furthermore, you join table `DATA_IZIN_BODY`, but it is unclear why it is used; all the desired fields for the result seem to be included in `DATA_IZIN_DETAIL` and `DATA_IZIN_DETAILPC` as well. If my answer does not work for you because of invalid or incorrect assumptions about the data structure, can you please update your question so that it contains information that more accurately represents your actual scenario?

Comment: unfortunately, i cannot union on DATA_IZIN_DETAILPC & DATA_IZIN_DETAIL table because the column structure is different. and the update has done @Bart Hofland

Comment: Is it possible to provide the CREATE TABLE statements for your three tables in your question? As I already said, I could provide a query with JOINs that would give the result you desire. Or I could make the UNION query working. But in both cases, more information about the data structure (column data types) of your tables is needed (because the result should show data from both tables combined).

Comment: and also for @Bart Hofland, thank you for the time you've spent to help to figure out my problem. big thanks!